# Parsing JSON data from a curl API request

Tags: curl, json, jq

I'm using Shodan's API https://developer.shodan.io/api to get my current network alerts. I want to parse out the id for the alerts with jq.

The curl request is `curl -X GET -i https://api.shodan.io/shodan/alert/info?key={API KEY}`

The output of that request is json data fomatted like so:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Test Alert",
  "created": "2017-01-09T21:53:17.104000",
  "expires": 0,
  "expiration": null,
  "filters": {
   "ip": [
    "198.20.88.870"
   ]
  },
  "id": "HKVGCP1WD79Z7W2T",
  "size": 1
 }
]
```

Using `curl -X GET -i https://api.shodan.io/shodan/alert/info?key={API KEY} | jq '.id'` give the following error:

```
"parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-i` option means curl will include http response headers which are not in JSON format.  That is what causes your parse error, however given the json you provided, you need to use `[]` to tell it to iterate the array:

```
curl 'https://api.shodan.io/shodan/alert/info?key={API KEY}' | jq '.[].id'
```

alternatively (and IMO more intuitively) using [json](https://github.com/trentm/json):

```
curl 'https://api.shodan.io/shodan/alert/info?key={API KEY}' | json -a id
```

Additionally json(1) has the `-H` option to ignore http response headers so you could use `json -Ha id`

Comment: First solution worked, had to remove the -i on the curl. Thanks!